# Android Intent issue

Tags: android

I want to show the details of a calculation in another activity when click on a button. How to achieve this. my first activity java code is

```
public void onClick(View v)
    {
    if(v.getId()==R.id.Button07) 
    {
        String a,b;
        Integer vis;
        a = txtbox3.getText().toString();
        b = textview1.getText().toString();
        vis = (Integer.parseInt(a)*Integer.parseInt(b))/100;
        tv.setText(vis.toString());  
                    // tv is a textview where result be shown

                    Bundle bu=new Bundle();
        bu.putString("answer",tv.toString());
        Intent intent=new Intent(AdvancedCalculator.this,calculatedData.class);
        intent.putExtras(bu);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

On clicking the submit button a new activity should appear with the results in a layout that is already defined.

My second activity class is

```
Bundle b=getIntent().getExtras();
String answer=b.getString("answer");
```

when i am trying to run the application the app crashes.

Any help will be appreciated  Thanks

Comment: Not sure if that is your issue, but you can put the extra string directly on the Intent by doing intent.putExtra(key, stringValue)

Answer (score 0):

One common problem is failure to add the second intent to the manifest as in:

```
    <activity android:name= "calculatedData"
        android:label="Data">
    </activity>
```